# Logic behind making a checkers game?

Tags: java, applet, logic

I'm starting to make a checkers game and I've got all my graphics plus the board drawn. 
Before I moved on to creating the pieces I was wondering what an easy way to tackle the logic side of the movement of pieces.. Should I make a table of every square, detecting if it has a piece and if so, what color? (i.e 0=empty, 1=red, 2=black) or do you guys have a better idea to this issue?

Comment: Possibly better on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Refer this:- http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1147465

Comment: Are you asking about an algorithm for the computer to pick moves, or are you looking for logic to track the board position for two (presumably human) players?

Comment: @Ted, the logic to track moves and pieces

Comment: Then your question is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946601/what-is-the-best-data-structure-to-represent-a-checkers-board-when-speed-is-the). There are some good answers there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using OOP principles I would go with something like:

```
enum Side {
  BLACK,
  RED;
}

class Position {
  int x, int y;
}

class Piece
{
  Position position; // position inside the board
  Side side; // which side the piece is
}

class Board
{
  Piece[][] board = new Piece[8][8];

  boolean isMoveLegal(Piece p, Position newPosition) {
    ...
  }

  void doMove(Piece p, Position newPosition) {
    if (isMoveLegal(p, newPosition) {
      // game logic of movement and eating other pieces if needed
    }
  }
}
```

A more naive approach could use a simple map:

```
class Position {
  int x, int y;
}

class Piece
{
  Side side; // which side the piece is
}

class Board
{
  HashMap<Piece, Position> board;

  boolean isMoveLegal(Piece p, Position newPosition) {
    ...
  }

  void doMove(Piece p, Position newPosition) {
    if (isMoveLegal(p, newPosition) {
      // game logic of movement and eating other pieces if needed
    }
  }
}
```

That can be use to avoid storing the current position of a piece inside itself.

Comment: So I would have to pre-define the pieces in the array?

Comment: This seems overly baroque. There's a lot of redundant data (e.g., the `Piece` stored at, say, `board[2][3]` needs to have `[2][3]` stored in its `position` attribute). Every time a piece moves, you need to update data in two places in a consistent manner.

Comment: It merely depends on where you want to place the logic of movement. I often found myself in situations in which it is better to have redundant data than finding a way to obtaining some information that you haven't planned to store before. Especially for a simple task like a checker game (it happened to find myself in the same kind of situation in a more complex environment and storing the position together with the element has been a good choice).

Comment: Without storing the position you couldn't be able to have a move logic without specifying the position in addition to the piece, it is a matter of taste, I prefer to have `move(Piece piece, Position newPos)` than `move(Piece piece, Position oldPos, Position newPos)` or even worse `move(Position oldPos, Position newPos)` (since you don't even need to know the piece from a compact point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a two dimensional array to represent the board.

```
int[][] board = new int[8][8];
```

Comment: I'm not going to write his checkers game.  He asked how to represent the board

Comment: Actually, he asked about the bookkeeping needed to keep track of moves. That's a bit more involved than just representing the board as a matrix.

Comment: Besides, this is a bad representation of a checker board, 1/2 your memory is unused, and you have to write a lot of routines the increment and decrement one index in coordination with another.