# checkers game logic/pseudo code?

Tags: python, pyglet

I am making a checkers game in python using the pyglet library. Up till now, I have been able to upload the graphics of the game. The problem is that I do not know how to make the logic/pseudo code of checkers. I do know that it is not possible for any of you to provide me the whole logic in here. So below are some ideas I have in mind. Please advice me if these ideas are correct and if any of them is wrong, what is the substitute?

1) Using an integer turn = 0 or 1, 0 means turn of black piece and 1 means turn of white piece.

2) Numbering the squares in the checkers board from 0 to 31.

3) Movement? Help me on this one. Just tell me the basic outline. I know that for the piece to move, there must not be any other piece in front or if opponent piece is there, it can capture it. This is the toughest part I can not figure out. Then, if there are two opponent pieces, it cannot capture the first piece as the way is blocked. Then, if an opponent's piece is infront of the player piece and opponents other piece is one space before its first piece, the player piece can jump two times and capture two pieces?

4) I have no idea about the king thing. If I can do the simple things first, I am sure I will be able to do this as well.

5)Win -> if all black/whitesprites,visible= false, particular player wins.

Here is my code below:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
from pyglet.window import mouse
from pyglet.window import gl

class checkers(pyglet.window.Window):

        blue = pyglet.resource.image('resources/blueSquare.bmp')
        red = pyglet.resource.image('resources/redSquare.bmp')
        blackP = pyglet.resource.image('resources/blackP.bmp')
        whiteP = pyglet.resource.image('resources/whiteP.bmp')
        spriteB = []
        spriteW = []
        screenWidth=600
        screenHeight=600
        x=None
        y=None
        w=None
        h=None
        def __init__(self):
            super(checkers, self).__init__(self.screenWidth,self.screenHeight,
            resizable=False,
            caption="Checkers",
            config=pyglet.gl.Config(double_buffer=True),
            vsync=False
            )
            platform = pyglet.window.get_platform()
            display = platform.get_default_display()
            screen = display.get_default_screen()

            self.x = 60
            self.y = 60
            self.red.width = self.x
            self.red.height = self.y
            self.blue.width = self.x
            self.blue.height = self.y
            self.blackP.height=self.y
            self.blackP.width = self.x
            self.whiteP.height = self.y
            self.whiteP.width=self.x
            self.h = self.red.height
            self.w = self.red.width
            self.x = (self.screenWidth - (self.w * 8)) / 2
            self.y = (self.screenHeight - (self.h * 8)) / 2

            for s in range(8):
                for i in range(4):
                    if s % 2 == 0:
                        self.spriteB.append(
                            pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.blackP, i * 2 * self.w + self.x + self.w, s * self.h + self.y))
                        self.spriteW.append(
                            pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.whiteP, i * 2 * self.w + self.x + self.w, s * self.h + self.y))
                    else:
                        self.spriteB.append(
                            pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.blackP, i * 2 * self.w + self.x, s * self.h + self.y))

                        self.spriteW.append(
                            pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.whiteP, i * 2 * self.w + self.x, s * self.h + self.y))
            for j in range(12,32):
                self.spriteW[j].visible = False
            for j in range(0,20):
             self.spriteB[j].visible = False

        def on_draw(self):
            self.clear()
            for s in range(8):
                for i in range(4):
                    if s % 2 == 0:
                        self.blue.blit(i * 2 * self.w + self.x, s * self.h + self.y)
                        self.red.blit(i * 2 * self.w + self.x + self.w, s * self.h + self.y)
                    else:
                        self.blue.blit(i * 2 * self.w + self.x + self.w, s * self.h + self.y)
                        self.red.blit(i * 2 * self.w + self.x, s * self.h + self.y)

            for i in range(32):
                self.spriteW[i].draw()
                self.spriteB[i].draw()

mygame=checkers()

pyglet.app.run()
```

My question maybe very vague or not specific but help needed please.

Comment: Your question is impossibly broad. You could start by creating a good data structure to represent the board position. Note that if your intention is to create a program that can actually play in a way which is even slightly competitive, you are going to need a very compact representation since you will likely be creating game trees with millions of nodes, where each node is a position. Thus -- you need something compact. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3946601/4996248

Comment: I am so sorry that my question is impossibly broad.  But, I could not help asking. I am just so confused.

Comment: of course your question is impossibly broad, you are trying to do something quite complex and you seem to miss a clear definition of structures and operations you want to use. Not that I would do better, just saying that it's not a simple task to start from scratch. Maybe you can find useful the definition of bitboard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard and also adapt some information from the more complex case of chess, for example here https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Getting+Started

Comment: thank you for your help above, I mean the links you gave. so here is a specific question, as you saw my code above, till now I have been able to create a board and generate sprites. I want to ask, that lets suppose, the user clicks on any of the squares of the board, I would like to print, "The user pressed mouse key on ___ square."